# Netezza UPDATE from one table to another

Tags: sql, netezza, ansi-sql

This is my query that does not work in Netezza:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET A.COL1= (SELECT DISTINCT B.COL1 FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.ID= A.ID AND B.DeptID=104)
WHERE A.DeptID=3
```

How do I re-write this query?
Please help.

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Comment: Netezza doesn't support subqueries like this...use join syntax instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET A.COL1 = B.COL1
FROM TABLE2 B
WHERE
A.ID = B.ID AND 
A.DeptID = 3 AND 
B.DeptID = 104;
```

Comment: I get an error  ^ found "INNER" (at char 57) expecting a keyword

Comment: sorry, forgot the from clause. I edited it - try it now.

Comment: Get another error error                                                                                                                                                                ^ found "B" (at char 157) expecting a keyword

Comment: Donal thanks for helping out. I was missing and AND crrected that but am getting another ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  relation does not exist DB.USER.A

Comment: That syntax may not work with Netezza. I have changed it to use a different syntax

Comment: Sorry still no luck.  ERROR:  Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Comment: That means it is working. It just means that there are multiple rows in Table2 that match the criteria in the where clause for 1 row in Table1. I cannot see what your data is like, so I am not sure how to modify the where clause to return just 1 row from Table2 for each row in Table1.