# Netezza Update Error from one table to another within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, netezza

Sometimes when doing updates by joining two tables, I get the following error:

> Please issue a groom on table 'X', maximum table versions exceeded.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? I am using a stored procedure and cannot use groom...

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE Table_1 t1
SET Var_1 = (CASE WHEN  t1.Var_1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE t2.Var_1 END)
FROM Table_2 t2 
WHERE t1.id =t2.id AND t1.Date = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(t2.Date, -1));
```

My two tables do not have more than 20,000 records. I have already reviewed this post:

[Netezza UPDATE from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165835/netezza-update-from-one-table-to-another)

But it does not address the error that I am getting...

Any idea of how to solve this kind of problem by using Update from one table to another?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the query to:

```
UPDATE Table_1 t1
    SET Var_1 = t2.Var_1 
    FROM Table_2 t2 
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND
          t1.Var_1 <> 0 AND
          t1.Var_1 <> t2.Var_1
          t1.Date = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(t2.Date, -1)) ;
```

This may or may not solve a resource issue, but it should result in fewer rows being updated.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for the error is not the update statement, but the table has been ALTER’ed many times and now it’s time to run a GROOM VERSIONS statement on the table.

Look at this ‘enzee community’ entry for a bit more detail, including how to identify all the tables you need to ‘fix’ this way - do it sooner rather than later!

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9c005573-d620-481c-9c62-490af78de4c9